# Seperate linear acceleration from gravity component from a built in smartphone's 3D accelerometer?

Tags: android, math, signal-processing, android-sensors

i am doing some gait analysis using the built in accelerometer of the smartphone on an android application in real time. The idea is to calculate the intensity of motion which is the magnitude of the three axes x,y and z and then for each window of the signal i calculate the standard deviation to detect if the user is in static or dynamic state based on a defined threshold.

I tried my algorithms on public datasets such as [MotionSense](https://github.com/mmalekzadeh/motion-sense) and the calculation are giving good result but from what i'm seeing it seems like in this public dataset there is no gravity effect on the acceleration axes contrary to the data collected from the smartphone.

For example when the phone is perfectly stable on a table the `z-acceleration = 9.81..` but i want it 0 [ in this case i have just to substract 9.81 from the z axis but it is not the case while moving, the gravity component affect all the axes ]

I tried a mathematical solution but i am not sure from the results.
here's what i tried :

> Calculate the magnitude of the acceleration vector:

`magnitude = sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)`

> Calculate the gravitational force:

`g = 9.81`

> Subtract the gravitational force from the acceleration vector:

`X_norm = X - (g * X / magnitude)`

`Y_norm = Y - (g * Y / magnitude)`

`Z_norm = Z - (g * Z / magnitude)`

Comment: More of a FYI: [Google Talk video on Sensor Fusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) and be aware that your public dataset is from an iOS device if comparing to personally collected Android data (i.e. what is and isn't in the data sets).